# Independent child object with references from multiples parents in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having quite the issue right now while trying to learn Entity Framework.
Let's say I have this entity:

```cs
public class BuildingGroup {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameOfManager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

And also this entity.

```cs
public class Architect {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Building> BuildingsBeingWorkedOn { get; set; }
}
```

These two entities are completely unrelated. Here's the `Building` entity:

```cs
public class Building {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

My problem happens when I try to add a building to, say a BuildingGroup. In my domain model, I can modify the equivalent collection of buildings, by adding, modifying or removing buildings. However, when I try to update `BuildingGroup` through a repository, the buildings will not be updated.

```cs
public void Update(BuildingGroup buildingGroup) {
    var buildingGroupEntity = _context.BuildingGroups.Single(b => b.ID == buildingGroup.ID);

    // This will not map the Building collection
    context.Entry(buildingGroupEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(buildingGroup);

    // My attempt at mapping the buildings
    buildingGroupEntity.Buildings.Clear();
    buildingGroup.Buildings.ToList().ForEach(b => buildingGroupEntity.Buildings.Add(_context.Buildings.Single(x => x.ID == b.ID)));

    _context.Entry(buildingGroupEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This fails if the building were not saved in the database prior to the call to `Update()`, which is normal since buildings can live independently. It must also be done for every child collection of `BuildingGroup` (if there were more), and for child collections of these children, well...

I have noticed other people use a foreign key constraint in the child object (here, `Building`), but I can't really do that since many unrelated entities can point to a building: I'd have a lot of navigation properties.

Is there a graceful way to manage referencing objects that can also live independently from those who hold references to them?

Answer (score 0):

If all the entities have to exist independently, yet have relationships with each other, it's better to use many-to-many relationship.

Change your model classes as follows, the Building should contain a couple of collections for architects and groups.

```
public class BuildingGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameOfManager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}

public class Architect
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Building> BuildingsBeingWorkedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Architect> Architects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BuildingGroup> BuildingGroups { get; set; }
}
```

If you use entity type configuration, you could define the relationship as follows:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Building>().HasMany(it => it.Architects).WithMany(it => it.BuildingsBeingWorkedOn);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Building>().HasMany(it => it.BuildingGroups).WithMany(it => it.Buildings);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Requirements I have say that a building can only be part of one building group, for instance. But I understand what you mean. However, won't keeping these circular references cause problems when I map these entities to domain objects? Looks like I'd have great amounts of object duplication too.